How to Exclude Tagless Structs Using ASTMatcher?
I'm currently working with Clang's ASTMatcher to extract struct declarations and exclude tagless structs. Here's an example of the kind of struct I want to avoid matching:
#include <stdlib.h>

struct {
    int b;
} a;

int func() {
    a.b = 1;
    return 0;
}

For my matcher, I used:
auto structDeclMatcher = recordDecl(
    isExpansionInMainFile(),
    isDefinition()
).bind("structDecl");

I also tried using isAnonymousStructOrUnion() and unless(hasName("")) to exclude those structs, but neither approach worked. Structs without a tag still seem to get matched.
How can I modify my ASTMatcher to effectively exclude those structs and only match tagged structs? Are there any specific matchers or conditions I should use to differentiate between named and structs without a tag?

It might help to use the right terminology.  What you present is not an anonymous structure type.  It is one without a tag.  An anonymous structure is something else, at least as far as the specification's terminology goes.

@JohnBollinger Thanks for your suggestion! I've updated the terminology accordingly. Apologies for any confusion.

I note that the Clang AST docs seem to use the term "anonymous" in yet a third way.  Your struct, being tagless, would be anonymous according to its declaration if no objects of that type were declared in that declaration.

@JohnBollinger Yes, you're right—if a didn't exist, it would be considered anonymous. However, what I'm actually trying to avoid are tagless structs. I used the wrong terminology :(

hasName
After some experimenting and code tracing, I found that, for a struct
declared without a tag, the effective name it uses for the hasName
Clang AST matcher
is:
(anonymous)

(This is a bit ironic considering this question's terminology history.
So it goes.)  See
getNodeName()
in ASTMatchersInternal.cpp.
Consequently, to exclude tagless structure declarations with hasName,
use:
unless(
  hasName("(anonymous)")
)

matchesName
Alternatively, if you use matchesName (which accepts a regex), then
the effective name is entirely different(!).  In that case, a tagless
record declaration has an effective name like:
::struct (unnamed at /full/path/to/test.c:3:1)

The exact construction comes from
TypePrinter::printTag()
and the
matchesName
definition.  Note that it has the leading :: even if the input code
was compiled as C, and that printTag() has some behavior variation
depending on language options.
Consequently, to exclude tagless structure declarations with
matchesName, use:
unless(
  matchesName("[`(]unnamed")
)

The regex accepts either backtick or open paren before unnamed because
the former is used when emulating MSVC and the latter otherwise, and
because omitting the punctuation requirement would let it match structs
that have a name that happens to include the substring "unnamed" (and
instead requiring a following space would fail if
Policy.AnonymousTagLocations is not set).
Demonstration
We can use the
clang-query
command line tool (part of Clang) to test the match expression:
$ cat test.c
// test.c

struct /*no tag*/ {
  int b;
} a1;

struct HasTag {
  int b;
} a2;

// EOF

$ clang-query -c='m recordDecl(unless(hasName("(anonymous)")))' test.c --

Match #1:

$PWD/test.c:7:1: note: "root" binds here
struct HasTag {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 match.


Thanks for you detailed investigation and helpful answer! This perfectly solves my issue :) Also surprised by the terminology history behind it. Anyway, thanks a lot!

However, when I tried using the matchesName function, it didn’t seem to work as expected. I ran the following command:
clang-query -c='m recordDecl(unless(matchesName("[`(]unnamed")))' test.c
Surprisingly, it still matched the /* no tag */ case, which I didn’t expect.

@cardigan Interesting.  What version of clang are you using?

It is not an answer only clarification:
This structure is a tagless structure.
struct {
    int b;
} a;

In this example the inner structure is anonymous.
struct // <- tagless structure
{
    struct     // <- anonymous structure
    {
        int b;
    };

} a;


Thanks for your kind notification. I've changed the description.
